# Como agrupar array de objetos JSON com PHP

Tags: php, json, api

Estou recebendo uma string JSON de uma API, para exibir os dados estou convertendo a string JSON para objeto php, porém minha dúvida é se é possível agrupar esses objetos, por exemplo agrupar todos os clientes com o nome X. Como se fosse o group by do SQL.

**Código de requisição da API:**

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.com.br/v1/entidades/HoraTrabalhada?campos=pessoa.nome,totalHoraTrabalhada,valorTotalOriginal,proprietario.nome&page&pageSize=100&criterio",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: ",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {

    $json_obj    = json_decode($response);
    $clientes    = $json_obj->rows;

    foreach ($clientes as $cliente) {
        echo "Valor hora: $cliente->valorTotalOriginal - Cliente: " . $cliente->{pessoa.nome} . "<br />";
    }

    echo "<br />";
    echo "<a href='index.php'><button>Voltar</button><a>";

}

?>
```

**JSON recebido:**

```
{"rows":[{"id":101448.0,"pessoa.nome":"Nome da pessoa","pessoaId":"79271","totalHoraTrabalhada":"","valorTotalOriginal":"5,86","proprietario.nome":"Nome da pessoa","proprietarioId":"4204"},{"id":101447.0,"pessoa.nome":"Nome da empresa","pessoaId":"74115","totalHoraTrabalhada":"","valorTotalOriginal":"8,79","proprietario.nome":"Nome da pessoa","proprietarioId":"4204"}],"listSize":51229.0,"modulo":"HoraTrabalhada","pageSize":2.0,"page":0.0}
```

**var_dump(clientes):**

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (7) { ["id"]=> float(101800) ["pessoa.nome"]=> string(44) "Giovani" ["pessoaId"]=> string(5) "79271" ["totalHoraTrabalhada"]=> string(0) "" ["valorTotalOriginal"]=> string(4) "2,93" ["proprietario.nome"]=> string(13) "Gustavo Souza" ["proprietarioId"]=> string(4) "3940" } }
```

Comment: poderia postar o var_dump da variável $clientes?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, adicionei o retorno do var_dump na publicação

Comment: tenta fazer o foreach com o `$clientes->rows`